# What Pokemon characteristics are immutable as of gen 9 games?

Tags: pokemon-scarlet-violet, pokemon-ninth-generation

I'm picking up Pokemon games with Violet and learning about every additions made to the game since gen 2, I'm having a hard time figuring out what are the Pokemon characteristics you can't change through grinding the games.

If I'm not mistaken, besides the Pokemon shinyness, you can now change every other aspect of your Pokemon, right? IVs are uppable with training, EVs are grindable through items and resettables with enough berries, nature can be changed with spices...

Is shinyness the only immutable characteristic of your Pokemon or are there others?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you correctly wrote, shininess is immutable.

But there are other properties that can't be changed:

- Base stats
- Gender
- Actual Nature (mints only change the effect of the Nature)
- [Characteristic](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Characteristic) (indicates which stat contains the highest IV)
- Dudunsparce's form
- Maushold's form
- Size

Most of them are related to Pokemon's [Personality value](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Personality_value), which is randomly generated and can't be changed:

> A Pokémon's personality value is an unsigned 32-bit integer that is created when the Pokémon is first generated by the game. For Pokémon encountered in the wild, it is set upon encountering them. For gift Pokémon and Eggs, it is set upon receiving them or when the Day-Care Man finds the Egg.

Comment: Since the OP is asking about Gen9, Wurmple, Spinda, and Unown are not in Scarlet/Violet

Comment: @Wondercricket uhm right, I was thinking about Pokemon Legends Arceus, but that's 8th gen

Comment: Thanks, if I understand it properly, immutables are all flavor texts and cosmestics. You now have a full control on every stats related to fight if you grind enough right ?

Comment: @Oddrigue only as much as you can raise them, base stats are fixed and you can only give 510 EVs as always

Comment: @Oddrigue Not entirely. For example, confusion from eating a berry your Pokémon dislikes the taste of relies on the actual nature, not the effect caused by a mint - thus it's better to have a neutral nature (since they like all the flavours) and use a mint to make it the desired nature. You can also never lower IVs - a Trick Room Pokémon wants 0 speed, a special attacker wants 0 attack (in case they get confused and hit themself), etc.

Answer (score 2):

You mentioned "immutables are all flavor texts and cosmestics" in a comment, which isn't quite true. So here are the non-cosmetic things that can't be changed or are otherwise unobtainable through items:

- **Gender**: not purely cosmetic, it's relevant for species with mechanical differences like Indeedee, gender-locked evolutions like Salazzle and Gallade, and gender-dependent effects like Attract and Rivalry.
- **IVs other than 31**: 0 Attack is often desired on special attackers to minimize the damage from confusion and Foul Play and the healing from Strength Sap, 0 Speed is useful in conjunction with things like Trick Room or Gyro Ball, and sometimes even more specific numbers are desired (like a certain Speed to be faster than one thing but slower than another in doubles, or the infamous Lonely Stakataka of previous generations).
- **Nature**: while you can use a mint to change the nature's effect on stats, the original nature still applies for purposes of determining Toxtricity's form (they have slightly different movepools) and which of [certain berries](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Category:Berries_that_may_cause_confusion) will cause confusion.
- **Pre-evolution exclusive moves**: egg moves can be taught using the Mirror Herb and most other moves are learnable at will, but certain exclusive moves still can't be learned (or relearned if you forget them) after evolving, such as Spore on Breloom.

Comment: IVs of exactly 31 also matter. If you would have hyper-trained that IV, now you don't have to. Since base IVs can be inherited, this has the potential to save a lot of money in the long run, with careful breeding. There is no way to set the parent's base IV to 31, so there's no way to force the offspring to inherit an IV of 31.

Comment: "Gender" -> Fun Fact: Until Gen 6, Azurill would occasionally change gender on evolution due to M/F ratio differences of Azurill and Marill. The M/F ratios are still the same, but gender is retained on evolution